# Voltage supply fallback in very low-profile design

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi

I'm currently designing a PCB built around an [RP2040](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf), following the RPi Foundations guidelines on how their SoC should be hooked up.

This specific device will have a very small footprint (hence the 2040) and will normally be powered by a LiPo battery - however, a user should be able to program the device over USB.

By default the RP2040 schematics utilize an [NCP1117-3.3](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1117-d.pdf) regulator for power over USB, and it's easy enough to use a similar regulator to supply from a 3.7V battery.

However, as far as I'm aware, supplying from both the battery and USB port at the same time will damage the device. In order to prevent this I could simply add a jumper to force the user to select either the battery or USB as source. But I think there should be a more 'automated' solution to this as to user-proof the device as much as possible.

So in my idea the device will draw battery power by default, but should 'switch' to the USB's power as soon as the USB bus gets connected. I thought this should be easy enough with a PNP transistor - but as the 'standard' transistor is too large for the device's footprint I got myself lost in the world of transistor properties, and now I feel like I'm in over my head.

So to summarize: I'd like to gain some insight on the best practice to make this kind of 'switch' in power supplies when the higher voltage supply becomes available.

Thank you guys for any insights! :)

**Background**

I'm an IT guy by trade and I try to learn electrical engineering as a hobby, so asking a question like this is my attempt to gain more insight where my own research fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an OR controller.  You'll need an external MOSFET and some other little passives but you can get the controller in something as small as an 8-DFN which is 2x3mm.

Also the NCP1117 has a dropout voltage of 1.4V so your 3.7V Lipo won't be able to power it.

If you don't care about the losses, you might be able to use a common-cathode diode pair.  You can find those in packages as small as a 3-UDFN but a cursory look at the data sheet is not encouraging on the characteristics. Depending on your current draw, maximum tolerable voltage drop, etc., you'd probably have to go with something in a SOT-23 or -323.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for! So I could use a [TPS22110APWR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2110a.pdf) with it's typical application circuit and pick a voltage regulator that suits both supplies. Or use the [LTC4416](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4416fa.pdf) and give each supply it's own, suited 3.3V regulator. Is that right?

Comment: The TPS2110 looks like the smaller footprint solution.  I think that with either of them you would only need one voltage regulator, which would minimize the footprint.

Comment: Yes, i've gone with the [TPS2113PW](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs446/slvs446.pdf) - as it features fully automatic switching (preferring the higher voltage, which is exactly what I need in this case), and since I couldn't find a linear regulator for both the LiPo and the 5V (as the LiPo might just drop below 3.3V) I've gone with the [ISL9110](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/isl9110-isl9112-japanese-datasheet?language=en&r=529131) step-up/step-down converter. Thank you for your help! :)